# How can I create a shortcut to launch a batch file one folder up?

Tags: batch-file, shortcuts

I have been trying to create a shortcut to launch a batch file one folder up from the shortcut location. I have not been able to find and answer this.

I have been able to solve this using an intermediate batch file in the same folder as the shortcut as follows: `Intermediate.bat`:

```
@echo off
FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\") DO set curdrv=%%~dpV
start "" %curdrv%Oneup.bat
```

And the shortcut target is:
`%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c Intermediate.bat`

and the 'Start in' is left blank.

This way I can move these folders anywhere on the drive or another drive and the shortcut still works. However, I would like to leave out the Intermediate.bat file and launch the `Oneup.bat` directly. I tried:

`%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\") DO set curdrv=%%~dpV && start "" %curdrv%Oneup.bat`

in the Target of the shortcut, but it doesn't work.

Is there some trick to getting this to work?
Thanks

Comment: You need the double `%`s **inside** batch files and a single `%` in a `cmd` shell. In addition `%0` is only valid **inside** a batch file ... so you need to rethink what you are trying to do.

Comment: David - If I understand what you are saying, I cannot use the command line proposed as the Target in the shortcut, therefore what I am trying to do is impossible. Or might there be another method? - fhutt

Comment: Please be patient, I'm working on a solution for you ...

Comment: You have `Oneup.bat` in the top level directory of the drive?

Comment: No, one level up, that's why I have "%~dp0..\" in the Intermediate.bat. - fhutt

Comment: Just use `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "" ..\Oneup.bat`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I would like to leave out the Intermediate.bat file and launch the Oneup.bat directly.

> I tried:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\") DO set curdrv=%%~dpV && start "" %curdrv%Oneup.bat
```

> in the Target of the shortcut, but it doesn't work.

There are two problems with the above command (which is being executed in a `cmd` shell):

1. `%%` is used inside batch files and `%` in a command line.
2. %0 (used in `%~dp0`) is only valid inside a batch file.

You can use the following (simplified) shortcut target:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "" ..\Oneup.bat
```

As `..\` always returns the directory one level up from the current directory.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: I thought I tried that before. Couldn't get it to work. Must have misspelled the file name because it now works. Thank you for trying this. Also much simpler than what I was trying to do. - fhutt

Comment: It is a pleasure to give your answer the green tick.

Answer (score 0):

David's solution doesn't work for me (for whatever reason).

But this does :

```
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process \"..\The Name Of Your Batch.bat\""
```

Leave the "Start in" field of the shortcut empty.